# How to group unique COL1 values across unique COL2 & COL3 values from CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, hive, python-itertools

Seeking to transform a CSV table with schema COL1=INT, COL2=STR, COL3=STR as such:

Input sample

```
INT1, S1, S2
INT1, S1, S3
INT1, S2, S3
INT2, S1, S2
INT2, S1, S3
INT2, S1, S4
INT2, S2, S3
INT2, S2, S4
INT2, S3, S4
```

to an output CSV/table where unique strings in COL2 or COL3 are output as COL1 followed by a list (in COL2 of output table/CSV) of unique COL1 INTs where they appeared.

Output CSV/table:

```
S1, [INT1, INT2]
S2, [INT1, INT2]
S3, [INT1, INT2]
S4, [INT2]
```

Comment: What does unique mean? Unique for a column or unique for column 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to vertically stack `COL2` and `COL3` into long format. Second, you can now use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by the melted column and get the unique values of `COL1` for each sub group (S1, S2, etc...):

```
# create example df
df = pd.DataFrame([["INT1", "S1", "S5"], 
                   ["INT1", "S2", "S3"],
                   ["INT2", "S1", "S2"],
                   ["INT2", "S1", "S3"]],
                  columns=["COL1", "COL2", "COL3"])
print(df)

    COL1    COL2    COL3
0   INT1    S1      S5
1   INT1    S2      S3
2   INT2    S1      S2
3   INT2    S1      S3

result =  pd.melt(df, id_vars="COL1").groupby("value")["COL1"].unique()
print(result)

S1    [INT1, INT2]
S2    [INT1, INT2]
S3    [INT1, INT2]
S5    [INT1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `COL2` and `COL3` are equivalent, you can stack the two columns to long format, group by the values and find out the unique elements of the `INT` column with `set` function:

```
df.set_index(0).stack().rename("s").reset_index().groupby('s')[0].apply(set)

#s
# S1    {INT2, INT1}
# S2    {INT2, INT1}
# S3    {INT2, INT1}
# S4          {INT2}
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```